# Nested Iterator Java

Tags: java, interface, iterator

I'm having difficulty understanding how to use iterators and interfaces. I need to create a nested iterator using **interface** that traverses a deck of cards within a class (not using built-in List iterators). I then need to create a method that uses the `remove()` method from the iterator to remove and return.

This is showing errors currently but this is what I have at the moment.

```
public interface DeckIterator implements Iterator <Card> {

    public boolean hasNext();
    public Card next();
    public void remove();

}
```

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: interface extends not implements

Comment: What do you mean by nested, you have to extend Iterator if you want to use an interface don't implement it.

Comment: Please have a look on OOP concept https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement your iterator, you need a class that implements it. This is beacuse `interface`s does not implement concrete code, only declares methods.

If your interface `extends` (not implements) `Iterator` interface, then there is no need to declare the inherited methods again, just:

```
public interface DeckIterator implements Iterator <Card> {
}
```

Now, you are ready to implement the code:

```
public class DeckIteratorImpl implements DeckIterator {

    public boolean hasNext() {
        //your code
    }

    public Card next() {
        //your code
    }

    public void remove() {
        //your code
    }

}
```

Actually, there is no need to create an intermediate `interface`. Just change your `DeckIterator` type from `interface` to `class`:

```
public class DeckIterator implements Iterator<Card> {

    //implement methods

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For `interface` `extends` another `interface` like this:

```
   public interface DeckIterator extends Iterator <Card> {
```

With `implements` means implementation, when interface just `declare` methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to create a **class** that implements the `Iterator` interface, with method bodies:

```
public class DeckIterator implements Iterator <Card> {

    public boolean hasNext() {
        // ...
    }

    public Card next() {
        // ...
    }

    public void remove() {
        // ...
    }

}
```